# Which of those two Ajax jQuery calls is faster?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a static html page where I'm doing some same-domain ajax calls. We have lots of them, so I wonder which is the faster way to get them done.
I have explored two alternatives:

Using .load:

```
$(window).load(function() { 
    $('.box').load("https://website.com/articles #content .list .article"); 
});
```

Using .ajax:

```
$.ajax({
           url: "https://website.com/articles",
           type:'GET',
           success: function(data){
               $('.box').html($(data).find('#content .list .article').html());
           }
        });
```

Which is theoretically faster? I didn't notice a lot of difference between them.

Also, would there be a better way to have many of those calls made?

Do both calls have to "parse" the full target page to find the specific `divs`?

Comment: The main delay comes from the HTTP request/response (transmission). The response-processing code that you have there only represents a tiny fraction of that time. The volume of the data that is transmitted could be reduced if you made a real API instead of full HTML-responses, which apparently have much more than what you are interested in.

Comment: Why would one be faster than the other when one is just a shortcut to the other?  In theory, `.load` will be *slightly* slower (maybe 0.01ms over a billion calls) as it's essentially `function load(..) { return $.ajax({type:"GET", ...`

Comment: @trincot could you point me to some resource to build a simple API to that effect? Coding is not my trade :)

Comment: Such an API would be server sided. Look for rest services. It all depends what your application server is. Could be PHP, Node, .Net, ... Research and try.